# How can i display new updated four images?

Tags: php, fetch

My php code is -

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'moviefone';
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_hindi") or die(mysql_error());
$info=NULL;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
  {
  $info=$row;    
  }
?>
```

and the html is

```
<div id="main_column">    <div class="column-1">
<div class="sub-column1">
<a href="#" class="new_movies"><span>New</span></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $info["images"];?>" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles"><?php echo $info["title"];?></a>
  <a href="#" class="new_english"><span>New</span></a>
</div>
<div class="sub-column1"> 
  <a href="#"> <img src="#" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles">nothing</a>
  <a href="#" class="theater"><span>In THEATERS</span></a> 
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example8</a>
   <a href="#" class="upcoming"><span>Upcoming</span></a>
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1"> 
   <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200"  class="new-img"/></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example12</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
<div class="column-2">
<div class="sub-column1">
  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $info["images"];?>" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles"><?php echo $info["title"];?></a>
</div>
<div class="sub-column1"> 
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example5</a> 
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example9</a>
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1"> 
   <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200"  class="new-img"/></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example13</a>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="column-3">
<div class="sub-column1">
  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $info["images"];?>" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles"><?php echo $info["title"];?></a>
</div>
<div class="sub-column1"> 
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a> 
  <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example6</a>
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example10</a>
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1"> 
   <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200"  class="new-img"/></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example14</a>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="column-4">
<div class="sub-column1">
  <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $info["images"];?>" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles"><?php echo $info["title"];?></a>
</div>
<div class="sub-column1"> 
  <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
  <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example7</a> 
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200" class="new-img" /></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example11</a>
   </div>
   <div class="sub-column1"> 
   <a href="#"> <img src="images/packshot._UX140_CR0,0,140,200_V1349717863_Lovefilmgb169343_.jpg" width="140" height="200"  class="new-img"/></a>
   <a href="#" class="img_titles">Example15</a>
    </div> 
</div>
</div><!--main cloumn-->
```

only one newly updated image is fetching.but i want four newly updated updated images to be fetched and displayed on the page.i can't achieve this.every row is fetching the same image . how to loop the latest entry of database?

Comment: You should explain your issue more. What's "newly update images"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: actually i want to display four latest updated entry.but the problem is that it only displays one latest entry.my question is that how can i display four latest entry ?as ex:i have inserted img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg.but its only displaying img4.jpg.what i want to achieve is to display  all the four images.

Comment: You just repeated yourself. That's already in your question's text. Please edit your question to better describe your goals as well as the problem. And less code please, only the relevant part! _(I never thought I'd say this...)_.

Comment: can you please tell me which part of my question is confusing.it may help me better describing my problems.